# Does ember require routes?

Tags: ember.js, wordpress

I'm writing a [feed reader plugin for wordpress](http://github.com/mattkatz/Wordprss).
Feeds have entries. Click on a feed, show the entries from that feed.

I have that working in older versions of ember, but when I try to upgrade to the release candidates it seems like we have to have a router. Defining routes etc is turning into a major headache and I'm wondering if I can just use the databinding that I came to ember for.

Is there a way to just use the databinding to controllers and models without having to go through the whole router business?

Comment: I can feel your pain, going from an older version of Ember to the newest. I can also confirm though that your code will be much less verbose, and less tightly bound together if you take the effort to rewrite the necessary parts of your app. You might consider checking out the Peepcode Ember video for a good overview of the new Router. It's only $12 USD.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to just use the databinding to controllers and models without having to go through the whole router business?

Yes it's possible to use ember without the router. It will still be there in background but won't cause any trouble. Just set `location: 'none'` and then customize  `App.ApplicationController`, `App.ApplicationView` and `application.hbs` as necessary. You may find it is still useful to customize the `App.ApplicationRoute` as well.

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'none'
});
```

FWIW @commadelimited is right, checkout the Peepcode video and consider taking advantage of the router.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. I'm having trouble getting the routes to resolve, not with the concept of using the router.

Answer (score 0):

Ember's routes have smart defaults so if you're app is pretty basic, you may not need to touch the routes.

location:none simply makes it so you're url doesn't show state changes, which can be useful

If you're app doesnt have any use for routes(maybe it's super small) you can simply put everything into a controller on your initial state/route and not worry about it.

But even if you have a simple setup of a few states:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("index", { path: "/" }, function(){
        this.route("stuff", { path: "/stuff" });
        this.route("otherstuff", { path: "/otherstuff" });
    });
});
```

the routes default action is take care of the magic behind that, so you shouldnt need to do anything :)

Comment: Thanks - I understand pretty well how the router works, but it doesn't seem to function well against the kind of URL I'm using. I'm in a wordpress plugin, so the url is like this: http://localhost/~matt/wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wordprss.php#/feeds

The router seems to not fire properly for these kinds of urls.